# Magnify a mirror reflection using a magnifying lens

Tags: reflection, lenses

Is it possible to magnify the image reflected from a mirror using a magnifying glass?

Like if the mirror is inclined 45 degrees in respect to the beholder, and the lens is placed in front of the mirror, can the beholder see the image in the mirror magnified?

Comment: What do you think? Have  you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried, the image on the lens was very blurry, and in focus was only the surface of the mirror with its little particles of dust. 
In the meanwhile I've discovered that this is exactly the way a Newtornian Telescope works, but I still don't understand if the focal length of the lens used, must be the sum of the distance between the object and the mirror plus the mirror and the lens.